# Why my PHP loop does not work? Or do I have to add 'if'?

Tags: php, loops

- Supposing I am driving a car along a loop. On the loop, there is a
  door. Every time I want to drive through the door, I need to spend
  some money.
- Originally the money I have is 100,000.
- When the money I have is more than 50,000, I spend 5% of them as
  the pass-door fee.
- When the money I have is equal to or less than 50,000, I spend 5,000 as the    pass-door fee.
- I want to figure out I many times I can pass the door.
- The first while loop works. But the second while loop does not work. Could you please let me know why?

```php
$money = 100000; // the original money I have
$a = 0; // $a defines how many times I can spend the money

// When the money I have is more than 50,000, I spend 5% of them as the pass-door fee.
while ($money > 50000) {
    $money= $money * 0.95; // The money left after each spending
    $a++; // How many times I can spend the money.
}

echo $a.'<br>'; //$a=14    So far I have passed the door 14 times.
echo $money.'<br>'; //$money=48767.497911553    So far I have 48767.497911553 money left.
```

My question is why the following codes do not work?

```php
// When the money I have is equal to or less than 50,000, I spend 5,000 as the pass-door fee.
while($money<=50000) {
    $money = $money - 5000; // The money left after each spending
    $a++; // How many times I can spend the money.
}

echo $a.'<br>';
echo $money. '<br>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second loop you pass as long as you have less than 50,000 and since you only decrease your amount of money, you'll stay in there for ever, i guess you want to stop it once you reach 0$ or less, so you could do that:

```
while($money >= 0 && $money<=50000)
```

In this case the loop will stop decreasing your money as soon as you reach 0 or below. If you want to loop until you can't pay the fee anymore just do:

```
while($money >= 5000 && $money<=50000)
```

Answer (score 2):

First I check I have still money:

```
$money = 100000; //the original money I have
$a= 0 ; // $a defines  how many times I can spend the money
$b = 0; //defines how many turns I have done;
while($money>0){
    if($money>50000){ //First option - i loose 5% of my money
        $money = $money * 0.95;
        $b = $b+1;
    }else{ //I already know that I have money
        if($money>5000){ //I can do another turn
            $money = $money - 5000;
            $b = $b + 1;
        }else{ //I have less then the money I need to do another turn
            echo "You made $b turns and now you have only $money left";
            $money = 0; //I reset the money so I get out of the while loop
            exit(); //i go out of the loop since I have nothing more to spend
        }
    }
}
```

With these figures the result of this code will be:

> You made 23 turns and now you have only 3767.497911553 left

I didn't get if you also want to simulate how many times left you have when you do one turn. This would lead to a different setup of the program.

Comment: Hi Lelio, thank you for your answer.:) Very informative. I am confused though. I changed the beginning of my second while loop from 'while($money<=50000)' to 'while($money<=50000 && $money>=5000)' according to @xoxel, and it works. But the result I have got is that I made 23 turns, not 22. I was wondering why our turns results are different? Our results for money left are the same.

Comment: You are right. I reduced the money before checking the money left. See the edit

Comment: Btw, it is always more efficient to reduce the number of loops you do. With this logic you just run one and get all the results you want

Comment: Thank you.I see the changes. May I ask what the purpose of $a is in your codes? I only see it once, and then it disappears?

Comment: You defined a as the number of turns left you can do. You code isn't doing any calculation on that. As I said in a previous comment I use b for the turns done. If you want to write something like: "You did 3 turns. You have 20 left" you need to use a and to change the code a bit

Comment: Oh, I see. Actually, what I intended to define with variable 'a' is just what your variable 'b' defines. Your definition is more accurate. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: There is another question that puzzles me. I was wondering if it is necessary to write '$money = 0; exit();'. I think when the money is less than 5000, so the loop will stop anyway.

Comment: you reduce the number of iteration of your code. It's just a very light code optimization. Let's the code do just what it needs to do. Same reason why I tell you do one loop instead of two. Start thinking about performance from the beginning.

Comment: Also, the less code you run for one goal the less error you are willing to do :-)

Comment: Yes, I understand one loop is better than two now. My two loops are the best I can do right now for a beginner like me. :) I will follow your kind advice to optimize my code. But if less is better than more, why not just omit '$money = 0; exit();'? Isn't the loop will stop by itself when  the money is less than 5000?

Comment: It will run again on an infinite loop and each time it will repeat the echo.

Comment: Thank you. I see now. :)

Answer (score 1):

`while($money<=50000)`

Your money will never be bigger than `50000` in your second loop because you just decrease it `$money=$money-5000;` so you enter in an infinite loop.

Comment: We completely misunderstood, the second loop goes right after the second, it isn't replacing it.

Comment: `$money=48767.497911553` when entering 2nd loop

Comment: Exactly, it enters there, and stays there. It never leaves. Because you are only decreasing the value. So the condition is always met. You are in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your second loop condition :

```
while($money<=50000)
```

This will always be true, since you're decreasing the money you have.

So it should be `while ($money >= 5000)` since you must have at least 5000 to pay the fee

Comment: `$money=48767.497911553` when entering 2nd loop

Comment: I know, but this be will an infinite loop, since he will stay in this loop as long as $money <= 50000, and that it will always be

Comment: @DarkBee oh okay, I was just confused about getting downvoted :)

Comment: I was confused by the part of OP saying 'the first loops works, the 2nd doesn't.', but clearly with an infin loop the page should just throw an error (most likely execution timed out)